# How do I batch delete a specific file inside multiple rar archives?

Tags: bash, delete, archive, batch

I have about 1000 rar files, that randomly contains an EXE file named:"JPG-Crack.exe".
I need to delete it from all archives without harming the other archive content.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

To delete files in a rar archive we may use the option `d`. This can easily be integrated in a recursive action like e.g.:

```
for f in *.rar; do rar d "$f" JPG-Crack.exe; done
```

The above command will find and delete `JPG-Crack.exe` files in all `*.rar` archives of the current directory.

Comment: double quoting `$f` would not hurt...